# Getting an element reference in a Custom Element

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, lit-html

Say I have a custom element. It consists of two parts, a button to open and toggle a menu and the menu itself. I want to position the menu directly below the button (`position: absolute`), but the button's height can be different depending on the theme. How do I find out the button's height before the first render?

**Simplified example:**

```js
import { render, html } from 'lit-html';

class Dropdown extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.root = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });

    this.update();  
  }

  get template() {
    return html`
      <style>
        button {
          height: 30px;
        }

        #dropdown-wrapper {
          position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
        }

        #dropdown-menu {
          position: absolute;
          top: ${dynamicButtonHeight}px;
          left: 0;
        }
      </style>

      <div id="dropdown-wrapper">
        <button type="button">Dropdown</button>

        <div id="dropdown-menu">
          <slot></slot>
        </div>
      </div>
    `;
  }

  update() {
    render(this.template, this.root, { eventContext: this });
  }
}
```

As you can see in the example, I want to know the button's height on the initial render and fill the `dynamicButtonHeight` variable somehow.  In this example, it's 30px, but this could be any number really. The same applies for the width, in case I want to align the menu to the right.

I know that I could render the markup initially and get a reference to the button using `this.root.querySelector("button").offsetHeight` and re-render afterwards. Although this would be efficient thanks to lit-html, I feel like this is dirty and breaks in certain use cases.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I find out the button's height before the first render?

You can't because the rendering engine **sets** the height

There is another potential issue

**Any CSS change can re-render your button**

The (not so new) ResizeObserver notifies you of those changes

so inside a connectedCallback() you could do:

```
this.observer = new ResizeObserver(entries=>{
  // check whether you need to (re)set stuff here
});
this.observer.observe(this)
```

Note (*this had me baffled the first 15 minutes*) that the element you inject in the page immediatly triggers the ResizeObserver

ResizeObserver has been in Chrome for some years now. All evergreen browsers now support it.

#### https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/resizeobserver

#### https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver

[image]

Comment: I see that this is not as easy as I have thought it would be - using the ResizeObserver seems like an interesting solution, although the browser support worries me. Well, I'll try to implement that and go from there. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Yes, if you need to support older browsers **and** need info about every layout change you are stuck with a setInterval.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps since it sidesteps the issue of knowing the button's height and just positions the menu below (or to the right of) the button, regardless of height. I prefer this method in order to avoid absolute positioning and calculations that might get thrown off by box-sizing issues.

Apologies if you already considered this and really needed the button's dimensions, since this solution doesn't actually provide those.

---

1) Wraps the button in a div to force the menu to be rendered **below**

```css
button {
  height: 30px;
}

#dropdown-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#menu-contents {
  height: 100px; padding: 3px; border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdown-wrapper">
  <div>
    <button type="button">Dropdown</button>
  </div>
  <div id="dropdown-menu">
    <div id="menu-contents">menu here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2) Removes the dropdown-wrapper styling and uses "float: left" to place the menu to the **right**

```css
button {
  height: 30px; float: left;
}

#dropdown-menu {
  float: left;
}

#menu-contents {
  height: 100px; padding: 3px; border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdown-wrapper">
  <button type="button">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="dropdown-menu">
    <div id="menu-contents">menu here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think that this is the right solution. The button can be themed from the outside and can have a dynamic height, so the menu's position needs to be truly dynamic as well.